# Elasticsearch geo_point alternative mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Is there an option for mapping of geo_point fields(lat, lon) as a separate fields inside JSON?

My object has to be like this:

```
{
    "location": {
        "lat":"",
        "lon":""
    }
}
```

instead of this i want to define my object like below:

```
{
    "latitude"  :"",
    "longitude" :""
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring a `geo_point` you have the choice between a few different formats:

Format 1: as an object

```
"location": {
    "lat":"32.11",
    "lon":"-34.22"
}
```

Format 2: as a string

```
"location": "32.11,-34.22"
```

Format 3: as a geohash

```
"location": "drm3btev3e86"
```

Format 4: as an array (beware longitude goes before latitude)

```
"location": [-34.22, 32.11]
```

Those are the only four ways to define a `geo_point`. You can see more info in [the official documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html)

Comment: Thank you for your help!